# Flask 2.3.x tutorial login example failing to retrieve from sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I am working my way through the Python Flask tutorial on the official website but I seem to have run into an issue where after registering, I am unable to login because fetching data from sqlite always returns None. This is weird because when I run the exact query for login right after inserting data during the register endpoint I am fetching the results I am after. When a different endpoint-- in this case auth/login -- calls it there doesn't seem to be any data returned.

db.py is pretty simple and has a few functions to connect to and close the db after each endpoint returns

```
def get_db():
    if 'db' not in g:
        g.db = sqlite3.connect(
            current_app.config['DATABASE'],
            detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES,
        )
        g.db.row_factory = sqlite3.Row

    return g.db


def init_db():
    db = get_db()

    with current_app.open_resource('schema.sql') as f:
        db.executescript(f.read().decode('utf8'))


@click.command('init-db')
def init_db_command():
    init_db()
    click.echo('Init the database.')


def close_db(e=None):
    db = g.pop('db', None)

    if db is not None:
        db.close()


def init_app(app):
    app.teardown_appcontext(close_db)
    app.cli.add_command(init_db_command)
```

When the app is ran, init_app gets run in the factory function which runs init_db_command. This checks to see if the database connection exists and otherwise creates it and using this connection runs the schema.sql file. This creating of the sqlite db file works and in my instance directory I see a flaskr.sqlite file. After each endpoint call it runs close_db() as specified in the app.tearddown_appcontext().

The factory function looks like this

```
def create_app(test_config=None):
    # create and configure the app
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
    app.config.from_mapping(
        SECRET_KEY='dev',
        DATABASE=os.path.join(app.instance_path, 'flaskr.sqlite'),
    )

    if test_config is None:
        # load the instance config, if it exists, when not testing
        app.config.from_pyfile('config.py', silent=True)
    else:
        # load the test config if passed in
        app.config.from_mapping(test_config)

    # ensure the instance folder exists
    try:
        os.makedirs(app.instance_path)
    except OSError:
        pass

    from . import auth, db

    db.init_app(app)
    app.register_blueprint(auth.blueprint)

    # a simple page that says hello
    @app.route('/')
    def hello():
        return 'Hello, world!'

    return app
```

At the end I call init_app() and register my auth blueprint.

Within the auth blueprint there are two endpoints that I am testing, auth/register,and auth/login

```
@blueprint.route('/register', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def register():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']
        db = get_db()
        error = None

        if not username:
            error = 'Username is required'
        elif not password:
            error = 'Password is required'

        if error is None:
            try:
                db.execute(
                    'INSERT  INTO user (username, password) VALUES (?, ?)',
                    (username, generate_password_hash(password)),
                )
            except db.IntegrityError:
                error = f'User {username} is already registered.'
            else:
                return redirect(url_for('auth.login'))
        flash(error)
    return render_template('auth/register.html')


@blueprint.route('/login', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']
        db = get_db()
        error = None

        user = db.execute(
            'SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ?', (username,)
        ).fetchone()

        if user is None:
            error = 'Incorrect username'
        elif not check_password_hash(user['password'], password):
            error = 'Incorrect password'

        if error is None:
            session.clear()
            session['user_id'] = user['id']
            return redirect(url_for('index'))

        flash(error)
    return render_template('auth/login.html')
```

When I input the username and password for register everything goes fine. The "INSERT INTO" command executes successfully and the data gets inserted into the DB successfully.  I tested this by running

```
t = db.execute("SELECT * FROM user").fetchone()
print(t['id'])
print(t['username'])
```

Both of these print statements return the correct information WITHIN the /auth/register endpoint, but the /auth/login returns None as the result when trying to fetch data from the db with the following line

```
user = db.execute(
            'SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ?', (username,)
        ).fetchone()
```

I am not entirely sure why this is the case. The code is pretty much copy,paste from https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/tutorial/

Comment: Wild guess: make sure that `request.form['username']` actually contains your data and nothing more - check if it looks okay or empty, if it looks fine look for extra spaces etc.

Comment: Yeah I have checked. I was originally thinking this but the select * from user returns nothing in the /login endpoint. This indicates that the DB is truncated?